# How to Render a page / component in UseEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**I have below code -**

```
function checkIfSignedIn()
  {
    axios.get(`https://localhost:44301/api/login/ValidateLogin`)
         .then(res=>{ 
           console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data));
           setLoginCredentials({
            ...loginCreds,
            isLoggedIn:res.data
          });
            dispatch(StoreUserAuthenticationStatusAction(res.data));
         });
  }
 const iLoginCreds ={
    userName:'',
    password:'',
    isLoggedIn:false
  }
const [loginCreds, setLoginCredentials] = useState(iLoginCreds)

useEffect(() => {
    alert(loginCreds.isLoggedIn);
    return (
      <>
      <MainPage></MainPage>
      </>
    )
  }, [loginCreds.isLoggedIn])
 return (
         <>
         ...
         ...
         ...
         <FormGroup>
            <Button style={{width:'100%',backgroundColor:"#FCB724",color:"black",fontWeight:"bold"}} onClick={checkIfSignedIn}  >Sign in using our secure server</Button>
         </FormGroup>
         </>
        )
```

**In short what I am doing here -**

Upon button click - checking/validating credentials through api. Api sends - true/false
Then I am updating my state in setLoginCredentials and dispatching in store.
Triggering useEffect on state change - there I am rendering to MainPage (which is not getting rendered)

**What Is Problem ? -**

In this code , upon useEffect trigger , I want to render my page to MainPage.
By keeping alert , I have made sure that useEffect is getting appropriately triggered.
But I cannot see my page getting rendered.

Comment: useEffect runs after the render. afaik cannot directly affect the render. Why not use an if statement instead `if (loginCreds.isLoggedIn) { return ... }`? There might be no-need for that useEffect

Comment: @evolutionxbox my main concern with this approach is , will it trigger upon change in isLoggedin without using useffect?

Comment: Will _what_ trigger upon change? What do you mean by trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the JSX outside the useEffect, in the return of the functional component like so:

```
return(
    iLoginCreds.isLoggedIn
    ?(
        <>
            <MainPage></MainPage>
        </>
    )
    :(
        <>
                ...
                ...
                ...
                <FormGroup>
                        <Button style={{width:'100%',backgroundColor:"#FCB724",color:"black",fontWeight:"bold"}} onClick={checkIfSignedIn}  >Sign in using our secure server</Button>
                </FormGroup>
            </>
    )
)
```

Comment: What's wrong with a regular if statement?

Comment: Will it trigger a change in iLoginCreds.isLoggedIn without useeffect?

Comment: @evolutionxbox i prefer the ternary operator but you can use a regular if statement as well

Comment: @CSharper yes, it will because when you run the setState of a component, the component gets re-rendered if the state changes. So you dont need the useEffect

Comment: @AgusMariscotti fine will try this approach and get back.

Comment: Will _what_ trigger a change? This code only changes what's rendered based on state. Nothing is being triggered.

Comment: What will trigger a change here is the function fired when the Button is clicked. When it is clicked, it will fire the function that he defined where it fetches the data and then the state is set with that data, triggering a re-render. I did not copy that part of the code, just the return of the functional component